# $.post как отобразить страницу по обработки параметров

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net, reportviewer

Подскажите отправляю на страницу данные и хочу после обработки этих данных отобразить страницу. У меня данные уходят, но страница не отображается.

JS:

```
// отправляю данные
$.post("Reports.aspx", { reportObject: JSON.stringify(rptObj) });
```

Reports.aspx:

```
// получаю данные
if (!IsPostBack)
  {       
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["reportObject"])) 
      {
          JObject obj = JObject.Parse(Request.Form["reportObject"]);
          ShowReport(obj); // в obj данные есть проверил
      }

  }
```

Как мне отобразить страницу Reports.aspx, объясните по возможности где мой затуп?

P.S. Если где-то неправильно форматнул текст извините, пока новичок.

Comment: `jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`
Вы видите у себя третий параметр(success)? я у вас его не вижу!

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, а что туда поместить? function() { window.location.href = 'Reports.aspx' } страницу откроет но пустую уже.

Comment: `function(data) { document.documentElement.outerHTML = data; }`

Comment: @Igor, в консоле возвращает мне по нажатию на кнопку(которая отправляет данные на Reports.aspx) Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'outerHTML' property on 'Element': This element's parent is of type '#document', which is not an element node.

Comment: `function(data) { $(document.body).html($(data).find("body").html()); }`

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: + и куча кода)) в конце: </body>
</html>
    at Function.Sizzle.error (jQuery-1.9.1.js:4421)
    at tokenize (jQuery-1.9.1.js:5076)
    at select (jQuery-1.9.1.js:5460)
    at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jQuery-1.9.1.js:3998)
    at init.find (jQuery-1.9.1.js:5576)
    at new init (jQuery-1.9.1.js:196)
    at jQuery (jQuery-1.9.1.js:62)
    at Object.success (Scripts.js:676)
    at fire (jQuery-1.9.1.js:1037)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jQuery-1.9.1.js:1148)

Comment: @Igor, я не знаю важно это или нет. функция ShowReport(obj) строит отчет на основе прилетевших данных ( через ReportViewer). Если на странице(test.aspx)  сделать ссылку( с href='Reports.aspx'), и данные никакие не отправлять а сделать статичными то все отлично работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, Вам не нужен `$.post`.

Вместо

```
$.post("Reports.aspx", { reportObject: JSON.stringify(rptObj) });
```

сделайте так (на странице есть форма?):

```
var hidden = $("<input name='reportObject' type='hidden' />")
hidden.val(rptObj);
$("form").append(hidden);
$("form").attr("action", "Reports.aspx");
$("form").submit();
```

Comment: идею понял. щас попробую, отпишу

Comment: большое человеческое спасибо. Все прекрасно функциклирует. =)

Comment: @Odyssey На здоровье. Успехов!